# Can I check which devices are connected to the router I'm connected to through a range extender (Booster)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, network-monitoring

We have a wireless internet connection here in our flat. But in my room, I don't get the Wifi range, so I'm using a TP-Link Range extender/Repeater/Booster to get the range. So right now I'm connected to the Range extender and not to the actual Wifi router. 
Is there a way to know the which devices are currently connected to that router? 
P.S. We share a same network. But I'm just connected to that router through the range extender.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Admin Page of Actual Wifi Router > Wireless > Wireless Client list > This would show you all client including the ones connected to range extender
2. Go to Admin Page of Range Extender > Wireless > Wireless Client list > This would show you all client connected to range extender

Subtract 2 from 1 and that gives you the list of devices just connected to Actual WiFi Router